# Selecting some following-sibling nodes only

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

I have the following XML:

```
<root>
<table>Table 1</table>
<foot>1.1</foot>
<foot>2.2</foot>
<p>...</p>
<p>...</p>
<table>Table X</table>
<foot>M.1</foot>
<foot>M.2</foot>
<p>...</p>
<p>...</p>
<table>Table 132</table>
<foot>A.A.E</foot>
<foot>234</foot>
<p>...</p>
<p>...</p>
</root>
```

I want to convert this to:

```
<root>
<table>
 <text>Table 1</text>
 <foot>1.1</foot>
 <foot>2.2</foot>
</table>
<p>...</p>
<p>...</p>
<table>
 <text>Table X</text>
 <foot>M.1</foot>
 <foot>M.2</foot>
</table>
<p>...</p>
<p>...</p>
<table>
 <text>Table 132</text>
 <foot>A.A.E</foot>
 <foot>234</foot>
</table>
<p>...</p>
<p>...</p>
</root>
```

I have the following XSL code:

```
<xsl:template match="table">
 <xsl:element name="table">
  <xsl:element name="text">
   <xsl:apply-templates />
  </xsl:element>
  <xsl:for-each select="following-sibling::foot">
   <xsl:element name="foot">
    <xsl:apply-templates />
   </xsl:element>
  </xsl:for-each>
 </xsl:element>
```

Which outputs as:

```
<root>
<table>
 <text>Table 1</text>
 <foot>1.1</foot>
 <foot>2.2</foot>
 <foot>M.1</foot>
 <foot>M.2</foot>
 <foot>A.A.E</foot>
 <foot>234</foot>
</table>
<p>...</p>
<p>...</p>
<table>
 <text>Table X</text>
 <foot>M.1</foot>
 <foot>M.2</foot>
 <foot>A.A.E</foot>
 <foot>234</foot>
</table>
<p>...</p>
<p>...</p>
<table>
 <text>Table 132</text>
 <foot>A.A.E</foot>
 <foot>234</foot>
</table>
<p>...</p>
<p>...</p>
</root>
```

How could only select the `foot` elements which are immediate to closing `table` elements, provided there will be `n` number of `foot` elements immediately following `table` element. Any help on this is appreciated.

Comment: Can you use XSLT 2.0?

Comment: Sorry. XSLT 2.0 is OK. I should have specified it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The cleanest way to do this is by using an XSL key. (The solution in this answer will work in all XSLT versions.)

```
<xsl:transform xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
    <xsl:output method="xml" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes" />

    <xsl:strip-space elements="*" />
    <xsl:key name="foot" match="foot" use="generate-id(preceding-sibling::table[1])" />

    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="table">
        <xsl:copy>
            <text><xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/></text>
            <xsl:copy-of select="key('foot', generate-id())" />
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="foot" />
</xsl:transform>
```

The `<xsl:key>` indexes all `<foot>` elements in the document using the unique ID (see [spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt/#function-generate-id)) of the immediately preceding `<table>`.

The `<xsl:template match="table">` then selects the `<foot>` elements that belong to each `<table>` with the help of that same unique ID.

---

The functional equivalent of this would be:

```
<xsl:template match="table">
    <xsl:copy>
        <text><xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/></text>
        <xsl:copy-of select="following-sibling::foot[
            generate-id(preceding-sibling::table[1]) = generate-id(current())
        ]" />
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

In this variant the XSL key would not be required. The result is in both cases:

```
<root>
   <table>
      <text>Table 1</text>
      <foot>1.1</foot>
      <foot>2.2</foot>
   </table>
   <p>...</p>
   <p>...</p>
   <table>
      <text>Table X</text>
      <foot>M.1</foot>
      <foot>M.2</foot>
   </table>
   <p>...</p>
   <p>...</p>
   <table>
      <text>Table 132</text>
      <foot>A.A.E</foot>
      <foot>234</foot>
   </table>
   <p>...</p>
   <p>...</p>
</root>
```

---

Notes:

- Don't use `<xsl:element name="text">`. You can simply write `<text>`. `<xsl:element>` is for situations where the element name is not predetermined.
- Avoid `<xsl:for-each>`. Working with `<xsl:template>` and `<xsl:apply-templates>` is superior in most situations.

Comment: For an XSLT 2.0 environment the solution presented by @michael.hor257k is of course nicer.

Answer (score 1):

Basically, this is a grouping problem. If you're using XSLT 2.0, you can take advantage of its built-in grouping features:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="/root">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:for-each-group select="*" group-starting-with="table">
            <table>
                <text>
                    <xsl:value-of select="."/>
                </text>
                <xsl:copy-of select="current-group()[self::foot]"/>
            </table>
            <xsl:copy-of select="current-group()[not(self::table or self::foot)]"/>
        </xsl:for-each-group>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```